# Zsh: argument autocompletion for `man` command

Tags: macos, zsh

Is there a native way to autocomplete the argument for the `man` command?

E.g.: `man loc<Tab>` to cycle through the options avaiable ("local", "locale", "localedef", etc...)

Not being able to do it wasn't annoying until it was :p

Comment: Do you have the "new" completion system enabled? (`autoload -Uz compinit; compinit`). Autocomplete for `man` works on my system, I'm not sure what I did to make it available.

Comment: @Gairfowl thanks! It works, now I know about the $FPATH. Later I will dip my toes in this. For now I'll just add this line of yours to my .zshrc and enjooooy. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `compinit` setting (as `in autoload -Uz compinit` mentioned by @Gairfowl) will show the completion functions from the $FPATH (where the functions definitions are). In the case of `man` it will get it from the `_man` file in the $FPATH. In my case I'm in macOS and it's located in `/usr/share/zsh/5.8.1/functions`